# Problems transforming toolbar on CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, wysiwyg

This is my code to display CKEditor4:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'description', {
    toolbar: 'Basic'
});
</script>
```

This works just fine and gives my the following options:

> Bold, Italic, Ordered List, Unordered List, Indent, Outdent, Link,
>   Unlink, About CKEeditor

My question is, without linking to an external config file, and using the code above, how can I make it so I only have the following options:

> Bold, Italic, Unordered List, Ordered List

This is the code I tried which broke the editor (it didn't display):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'description', {
    toolbar = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] }
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list'] },
    ];
});
</script>
```

Can anyone show me where I have gone wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missed the semicolon between objects in array.

You can remove unnecessary buttons with `.removeButtons` property:

```
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,JustifyCenter';
```

Use:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'description', { toolbar: 'Basic', removeButtons: 'Bold' });
```

Comment: Using this code it still breaks the editor: CKEDITOR.replace( 'description', {
    toolbar: 'Basic'
    config.removeButtons = 'Bold';
});

Comment: I'm sorry to be picky but using your code above adds a lot of buttons to the editor. It might be easier just to specify which buttons I want. This doesnt seem to work: CKEDITOR.replace( 'description', { toolbar: [[ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic' ]], );

Comment: Seems you're missed brace. Check `CKEDITOR.replace( 'description', { toolbar: [[ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic' ]] });`